# How to rerun a GitHub Action workflow from the command line and have the status check of the relevant pull request consequently be updated

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that can be triggered by a pull request and by workflow dispatch. It is always first triggered by the pull-request event. When the pull request triggers the workflow, the relevant status check appears on the pull request page.

In addition, I have requirements that require the workflow to be re-run on the same commit (from the command line) and update the status check in the pull request accordingly.

I manage to call the workflow dispatch using gh cli:

```
gh workflow run workflow_file_name.yml --ref "branch_name"
```

And the workflow indeed runs on the last commit on that branch, as the recent workflow run triggered by the pull request of that same branch.

The only difference is that the status check on the pull request page doesn't get updated due to the workflow dispatch.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You should probably run the check using the API instead of manually running the workflow: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#rerequest-a-check-run. To get the correct ID to pass in, use the LIST API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-check-runs-for-a-git-reference

Comment: @jessehouwing I tried what you suggested but I get this error message: "message": "This check run is not rerequestable". Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @jessehouwing this seems to work only with GitHub Apps, which is not my case. When I tried to just update the status of a status check I got the error message: "message": "You must authenticate via a GitHub App."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of hair-pulling, I found the easiest and fastest solution. So here it is to share with everyone.

```bash
RUNID=$(gh api repos/$OWNER/$REPO/commits/$COMMIT_SHA/check-runs | jq -r '.check_runs[] | select(.name == "NAME_OF_YOUR_GITHUB_ACTIONS_WORKFLOW") | .html_url | capture("/runs/(?<number>[0-9]+)/job") | .number' | sed 's/"//g' | head -n 1)
gh run rerun $RUNID
```

This results in the same workflow being rerun and its final status being updated in the relevant status check on the pull request page.

---

***Breakdown of the code:***

Use the gh cli command (you need to download gh from here: https://cli.github.com/):

```bash
gh run rerun $RUNID
```

I couldn't find a "clean" way to get the ID from the command line (using a script), so I improvised and found the information as part of the output of this GitHub API command:

```bash
gh api repos/$OWNER/$REPO/commits/$COMMIT_SHA/check-runs
```

The output is a JSON string. Find your item matching the name of your workflow and the RUNID number is located under the "html_url" field between the words 'run' and 'job'.

So I extract the RUNID using this command:

```bash
RUNID=$(gh api repos/$OWNER/$REPO/commits/$COMMIT_SHA/check-runs | jq -r '.check_runs[] | select(.name == "NAME_OF_YOUR_GITHUB_ACTIONS_WORKFLOW") | .html_url | capture("/runs/(?<number>[0-9]+)/job") | .number' | sed 's/"//g' | head -n 1)
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Thank you for this! I hit the same problem after writing a custom `git workflow run` GHA solution. `gh run rerun` did the trick re: associating the re-run with the PR.